# HTML/CSS - How to place left and right divs outside container?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a site built with [Ribosome theme](https://wordpress.org/themes/ribosome/). What I would like are 3 divs outside the main container which has a responsive width, but I'm not sure how to get this done properly.

[I want it to look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkCVd.png)

[image]

I accomplished the above image by creating an invisible div between the left and right divs, that pushes them to the sides. I feel like this is a bad way to do it as it requires JavaScript or CSS to set the right width of the invisible div between them. The top div is placed inside the container, so it uses its width.  This was the code:

```
    <div class="outside-mid" style="background-color:#333;width:100%;height:300px;"><a href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>
    <div id="outside-container" style="position:absolute;text-align:center;height:0;width:1144px;">
        <div class="outside-left" style="background-color:#333;width:300px;height:600px;float:left;margin-left:-310px;"><a href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>
        <div class="outside-right" style="background-color:#333;width:300px;height:600px;float:right;margin-right:-310px;"><a href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>
    </div>
```

I set the width of **outside-container** using JS:

```
<script>
    var width = document.getElementById('main').offsetWidth;
    document.getElementById("outside-container").style.width = width + "px";
</script>
```

What I'm asking is if there's a way to just put the left and right divs inside the container and then, without using any invisible div to push them, just float them to the left and to the right outside the container. This way it would end up being responsive as it would always use the container width.

Answer (score 1):

Set your html to look like this..

```
<div id="outside-container">
    <div class="outside-left"></div>
    <div class="main-div"></div>
    <div class="outside-right"></div>
</div>
```

and try this css..

```
#outside-container { width: 100%; }
.outside-left { width: 20%; float: left; }
.outside-right { width: 20%; float: right; }
.main-div { width: 60%; float: left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

please you can use this code.

[Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.](http://example.com)

```
<div id="outside-container" style=" background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) none repeat scroll 0 0;display: table; height: 0; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; width: 1144px;">
    <div class="outside-left" style=" background-color: #333333;float: left; height: 600px; transform: translateX(-100%); width: 300px;"><a href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>
    <div class="outside-right" style="background-color: #333333; display: inline-block; float: right; height: 600px; margin: 0 auto; transform: translateX(100%); width: 300px;"><a href="http://example.com">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of good answers here, but I found them quite hard to implement with the use of the same theme I already had installed. After looking through more solutions I found a way that worked for my case. I put the following inside the container, and it worked without altering the current layout.

```
    <style>
    #left:before, #right:before, #top:before  {
        position:absolute;
        content: "Ads";
        top:-20px;
        color: #fff;
    }
    #left:before  {
        right:0;
    }
    .site {
        overflow:visible;
        position:relative;
        top:340px;
    }
    </style>

    <div id="top" style="position: absolute; width:100%; height:300px; top:0; background-color:#888;margin-top:-310px;"></div>
    <div id="left" style="position: absolute; width:300px; height:600px; left: 0; top: 0; background-color:#888;margin-left:-310px;"></div>
    <div id="right" style="position: absolute; width:300px; height:600px; right: 0; top: 0; background-color:#888;margin-right:-310px;"></div>
```

Note: **.site** refers to the parent (container)